# How to convert to a Definite Clause Grammar

Tags: prolog, grammar, dcg, integer-partition

I'm trying to write a definite clause grammar that outputs the partitions of a number. For example `?- w(3,L,[])` should output :

```
[1,1,1]
[2,1]
[1,2]
[3]
```

My code looks as follows:

```
w(PosNumber) --> {partition(PosNumber,L)},L.

partition(0,[]).
partition(PosNumber,[X|List]):-
   between(1,PosNumber,X),
   Y is (PosNumber-X),
   partition(Y,List).
```

My partition function seems to work fine but I'm not sure how to correctly instantiate 'w'. Sorry if this is really basic, I'm very new to prolog.

Comment: It seems to work fine for me. Please try again to explain what is the problem.

Comment: If i put in the query `?- w(3,L,[])` I get the error `Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated
Reachable from:
   swish_trace:swish_call(w(3,A,[]))
   '$swish wrapper'(w(3,A,[]),B)`

Comment: It works fine in SWI Prolog. Are you using a web site or something?

Comment: Maybe you could move the error message to the question.

Comment: SWISH is SWI based, but is a subset of SWI Prolog capability.

Comment: ah yes im using swish.swi-prolog.org! just tried it in terminal and it worked fine! Didn't realise that could be a problem. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Why do you require a DCG? Seems perhaps more suited for CLP(FD). What you have isn't what I'd call a DCG implementation since you are immediately breaking into standard clauses right from the initial call. You wouldn't *instantiate* `w`. You'd call it: `phrase(w(N), Sequence)`.